# I need help in developing my android app

Tags: android

I used an app inventor site to help my with programming and I have two problems.

I need to notify the users every day with the schedule as follows:

- Saturday : Bible Verses
- Sunday :  Stories of the Saints
- Monday : Messages
- Tuesday : Christian Questions and Answers
- Wednesday :     Alerts
- Thursday : Christian Topic
- Friday : Christian Virtue

I need to send only one theme every day, not all of them.

I also need to let the users save their daily messages in their phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android APIs Make Use of **[Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)** Site

1. For Notification use Push Notification Services
2. For Store, the Messages  use SQLite

**Reference Links:**

- [Push Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) - [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/),[Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
- [SQlite](https://www.sqlite.org/) - [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Comment: @BishoyKhalaf This is not a Right place to Ask these Types of Questions Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry my friend .. am new user here , i apologize